# Being able to use VSCode attached to dev containers after an error in the container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I use Dev Containers to code in VSCode, I attach my container to vscode. But when I wrote something in my code that breaks the container it also break the vscode windows attached to it and I can't remove this piece of code that makes everything fails.

I need to reopen a new vscode windows that is not attach to the container, find my mistake in the code, correct it, restart the container and it's fine.

**I want to keep using this attach VScode window even if the container failed. HOW ?**